# How can I control max-age for particular files with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, http-caching, actiondispatch

I have Rails serving my static assets. Most of them have hashes in their name and are served with far-future expiration dates. But for one file, I can't serve it with a hash in its name, so I need to control the expiration date.

I have this in my application.rb which applies to all static assets:

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
```

Is there a way for me to have a different max-age for just one file? I know I can make a new middleware that comes after `ActionDispatch::Static` and changes the value for certain files (see [this writeup](http://www.hokstad.com/rack-middleware-adding-cache-headers.html))... but then this will run for every single request, even those which aren't static assets. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Is it okay to do it at the server level? Potentially makes more sense there anyway.

Comment: I don't have that option in this deployment (heroku).

Comment: I'm using heroku too and this has always been a burning question.

Comment: the `Rack::Static` solution here is working for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962896/how-do-i-prevent-rails-3-1-from-caching-static-assets-to-rails-cache

Answer (score 0):

A bad technique can be to fix the URL of your file in your route.rb. You can define a Controller to this route fixing the cache_control you want and use `send_data` method to server the file.

Comment: considered something like that as well... a messy path to go down but possibly the best solution in the end

Comment: it's the most simplest if you don't want add a Middleware. Or you need hack the ActionDispatch::Static middleware to do the job. Maybe replace it by example.